# subset data.table when condition is exactly met

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table,

```
str(zipShp2_dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5567625 obs. of  7 variables:
$ lat  : num  -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 ...
$ long : num  -171 -171 -171 -171 -171 ...
$ order: int  5145201 5145204 5145203 5145202 5145200 5145199 5145205   5145206 5145198 5145207 ...
$ hole : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
$ piece: Factor w/ 32 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ group: Factor w/ 42703 levels "00601.1","00602.1",..: 40916 40916 40916    40916 40916 40916 40916 40916 40916 40916 ...
$ id   : chr  "96799" "96799" "96799" "96799" ...
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
- attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "lat" "long"
- attr(*, "index")= atomic  
..- attr(*, "long")= int  5392777 5392778 5392779 5392780 5392781 5392782   5392790 5392808 5392802 5392813 ...`
```

I would like to retrieve the `id` value, for example:

```
tail(zipShp2_dt)
     lat   long   order  hole piece   group    id
1: 71.34 -156.6 5478987 FALSE     1 99723.1 99723
2: 71.34 -156.6 5478989 FALSE     1 99723.1 99723
3: 71.34 -156.6 5478986 FALSE     1 99723.1 99723
4: 71.34 -156.6 5478981 FALSE     1 99723.1 99723
5: 71.34 -156.6 5478984 FALSE     1 99723.1 99723
6: 71.34 -156.6 5478985 FALSE     1 99723.1 99723`
```

So I tried

```
zipShp2_dt[long==-156.6]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 7 cols: lat,long,order,hole,piece,group...
```

However, I can find, for example

```
zipShp2_dt[long<-156]
lat   long   order  hole piece   group    id
1: -14.32 -170.7 5145114 FALSE     1 96799.1 96799`
```

All the other operations where succssesful, except the exactly met.

The data.table is too large, so I created a `dput(head(zipShp2_dt))`, which can be found at `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B31RjzxWt16hY09oM0ppU21PR2M/view?usp=sharing`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is long in fact -156.6 for those values, or are they rounded in the display? You might want to do your comparison with round(long) in that case.

Comment: sounds like the auto-indexing bug in version 1.9.4 - disable auto-indexing or upgrade to latest devel version

Comment: When I use round(long,2) it works! Thanks @dd3!

Comment: use `options("datatable.auto.index"=FALSE)` or upgrade package to 1.9.5 - see [installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: You probably don't want to write an inequality like `long<-156` since `<-` is the assignment operator. (I'm not really sure why it's working here.)

Comment: @Frank Good point, I've filled [#1317](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1317) about it, please share you thoughts there.